# Extract list of content in a specific Portal webmap using ArcGIS API for Python

Tags: arcgis-portal, arcgis-python-api

I would like to extract the lists of content (Feature & Map Image Service) including the type of base map. Also, wanted to know if all the layers are loading correctly using ArcGIS API for Python.

```
import arcgis
portal = arcgis.gis.GIS("Portal URL", "Portal Username", "Portal Password")
maps = gis.content.search("WebMap item id")
for webmap in maps
    for lyr in webmap.get_data()['operationalLayers']
        print(lyr['title'])
```

I've extracted the layers but I would like to know the base map layers in the web map and the layer loading status